# How to pass value into another model based on conditional statement

Tags: django, countdowntimer

I want to create a countdown timer target that will be added into date_target model, using override save method in models.py, the time will countdown differently based on it's variety.

```
import datetime

class CustomerVariety(models.Model):
      variety = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
       
      def __str__(self):
          return self.variety


class Customer(models.Model):
      cardnumber = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False)
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
      date_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True,                                          
                                     null=True)
      date_target = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, null=True)
      variety = models.ForeignKey(CustomerVariety, 
                                  on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

      def __str__(self):
          return self.name

      def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          if not self.pk:
             if self.variety == "Priority Customer":
                self.date_target = self.date_in + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
             elif self.variety == "Secondary Customer":
                self.date_target = self.date_in + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
          super(Customer, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

when i pass value into form and save it, why date_target models doesn't full fill the value ?

Comment: ``self.variety == "Priority Customer"`` seems to be comparing a string to an object which will always fail. If you are happy using a string for your "customer variety" just use a string - your code will be simpler. For your forms you can have choices in the Customer model so you select the appropriate variety when editing.

Comment: oh it's work very well @PaulWhipp Thanks so much, but if i want using foreign key should i change my self.variety into self.variety == 1 or self.variety == 2.

Comment: No, hard coding the id is a bad idea. You should fetch the object and compare to that eg `self.variety == CustomerVariety.objects.get(variety="Priority Customer")`

Comment: ok, i got it. thanks, simple is the best